# onButtonClick vs. onMenuItemSelected ----- Not the same result

Tags: java, android, menu

I have a method deleteDilaog (it displays dialog with yes and no option. when clicked yes it does something, when clicked no it cancel dialog) and it is called either buy taping a button or on selecting a item in a option menu. Problem is, result is not the same? It works fine when selected from menu but when clicking a button it just displays dialog and no matter what i click,nothing happens?

Button:

```
private void RemoveAll(){

Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        deleteDialog();

    }
});

}
```

Menu Item:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int id, MenuItem item) {
    mDeleteId=item.getItemId();
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case INSERT_ID:
        addItem();
        return true;
    case DELETE_ALL_ID:
        deleteDialog();
        break;

    }

    return super.onMenuItemSelected(id, item);
}
```

deleteDialog method:

```
private void deleteDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setMessage

(CONFIRM_DIALOG_STRING).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton

(POSITIVE, new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int 

which) {
            switch (mDeleteId) {
            case DELETE_ALL_ID:
                mDbHelper.removeAllLists();
                fillData();
                break;
            case DELETE_ID: 
                Cursor c = (Cursor) 

getListView().getAdapter().getItem(which);
                mDbHelper.removeList

(mItemId);
                c.requery();
                break;

            }

        }
    }).setNegativeButton(NEGATIVE, new OnClickListener() 

{

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int 

which) {

            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = dialog.create();
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

Comment: Use dialog.dismiss() instead of dialog.cancel()

Comment: No. same result, working trough menu, not working with button

Answer (score 0):

A dialog firstly should never be called as you have coded. 
Make us of [Activity.onCreateDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateDialog%28int,%20android.os.Bundle%29) to initialise and maintain you dialog lifecycle

Activities provide a facility to manage the creation, saving and restoring of dialogs. Also See onCreateDialog(int), onPrepareDialog(int, Dialog), showDialog(int), and dismissDialog(int).

Comment: Im not sure how to do that. Im new in android development and all of the code is from the book im using to learn. In the book everything is handled by menu, but now i want to remove menu and add on screeen buttons

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is with mDeleteID. It is set in OnMenuItemSelected, but not in button2's onClick listener.

I'm guessing that the switch(mDeleteID) falls through when the button is clicked.

Comment: I dont think so. mDeleteID is just item in the list and its there so that method onMenuItemSelected can choose between deleting and adding. corect me if i am wrong

Comment: In your DeleteDialog's SetPositive onClickListener you decide on the action depending on mDeleteID's value, but this is only set in onMenuItemSelected and not when the button is clicked, so results may differ depending on the order in which you select the menu item / button.

Answer (score 0):

In case of button you're not setting a value to mDeleteId.